# Task running asynchronously on another thread .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I have a procedure that needs to be executed on another thread, asynchronously. The procedure will process a number of data in batches (can receive 2 items or 40000). From local tests, the longest runtime was about 2 minutes (for 40000 items).

The scenario is the following: UI call to back-end, back-end starts an asynchronous thread that will run the procedure and then returns a boolean, to know if the request was received or not (these are the requirements, I do not use await/wait). I am not quite sure what to use here, between:

```
Task.Run(()=> MyProcedure())
```

OR

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> MyProcedure(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
```

What would be the best option for this situation?

Comment: There is no difference between these two. One is an alias for another with some default parameters. They will be different in behaviour only if you call one of them every second, for example — `Task.Factory.StartNew` will create a lot of threads which will actually slow down the program.

Answer (score 1):

> The procedure will process a number of data in batches

This can mean multiple things. If you are going to use `async`/`await` in those batches, such that your `MyProcedure` is *actually asynchronous*, then you should be fine with `Task.Run`; the fact that `MyProcedure` releases itself back to the thread-pool whenever it has gone async means that this should work fine, for example:

```
async Task MyProcedure()
{
    while (ThereIsWorkToDo)
    {
       var batch = // ... gather some work
       await ProcessBatchAsync(batch).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

However: if `MyProcedure()` is *not* asynchronous, but you just want to run it in the background, then yes, `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` might be reasonable, but for something that takes 2 minutes: so might be a regular dedicated thread.

Comment: MyProcedure() is not asynchronous, I just want it to run in the background and not block my UI thread. It is not a rule that it will always take 2 minutes, this depends on the amount of data that the client selects. This is why I am not quite sure, because the operation can run for under 1 second most of the time but in some cases it might take up to 2 minutes (this is an approximation).

Comment: @user2399378 I'd probably use `LongRunning` to avoid problems in the bad case; it isn't a problem if something says it is long-running, but finishes quickly; however, I'd also probably put serious consideration into changing the method to *be* genuinely asynchronous. The fact that you say it usually runs in less than a second means the "dedicated thread" approach is not a great idea.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the behaviour will be and how many items will be selected per request, all I know is that the maximum is around 50000. What do you mean by changing the method to be genuinely asynchronous? I only need it to run on a separate thread in order to let the UI function properly, the code inside it can run synchronously.

Comment: @user2399378 if it works, then probably best to stop poking it, and stick with what you have